# HTML5 websocket client does not detect unexpected server disconnect

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I have a system where an html5 WebSocket client connects to a ws.js WebSocket server. Currently, ws.js has a built-in ping pong system to periodically check that clients are still connected and active. If a client unexpectedly goes offline the server can force a close on that client and clean up the connection.

However, if the WebSocket server unexpectedly goes offline. The html5 client doesn't receive the onclose event.

Is there any way to detect (preferably event-driven) the unexpected WebSocket server going down so that the client can run its onclose functionality?

I have a currently 'working' solution by implementing my own ping/pong polling mechanism. However I would rather this was more event-driven thank polled.

Thank you to anyone that can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the websocket server does not send the CLOSED or CLOSING readyState due to for example network failure, there is no event that detects this. ping/pong is the right way to handle this